# RTP audio stream works only in one direction in a SIP call

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, rtp

I'm developing software feature for a Session Boarder Controller(SBC).
I'm trying to establish a SIP call using two SIP clients and a Session Boarder Controller(SBC). Asterisk is used as the soft-switch.

When I call, the SIP signalling is working fine. But I am getting audio only in one direction. I captured rtp packets on all interfaces using wireshark. I observed that rtp packets in one direction is being dropped by asterisk.

Note: There is no send only attribute in any of the SIP/SDP messages.

I would like to know if there is any settings in asterisk that may cause this issue?

One more thing that I would like to know is that, from where a SIP client gets the RTP connection information. The port information is present in the media attribute

`m=audio 16388 RTP/AVP 8 0 101`

From where does the client get the transport IP address? is it from the "o=" field or "c=" field in the SDP or any other fields in the SDP or SIP?

Comment: Not a programming question, Media is connected using c= in SDP, (when there is no ICE) please contact Asterisk forum with the SIP logs.

Comment: @spicyramen Thanks! and sorry for posting this question here. I didn't find another suitable place to ask this question. I just thought who else, other than a programmer, can answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

You should troubleshoot the problem by capturing the complete call with Wireshark. Then look carefully at:

- Client A initial INVITE: which port is it expecting media on (m= line) which address is it expecting media on (c= line)
- SBC for Client A initial INVITE: If the SBC is anchoring the media (I assume so) check m / c lines
- SBC for Client B initial INVITE: Which port / ip (m/c lines) is SBC for Client A expecting media on
- Client B initial INVITE: Which port / ip (m/c lines) is SBC for Client B expecting media on

Are all nodes in this direction sending media on to the correct ports / ips (look at the RTP streams in wireshark)?

Then check the other direction (based on the SDP in the 183 or 200 (depending on your signaling flow)).

Note: In wireshark there is a nice feature which helps alot: Telephony --> VoIP Calls, which shows you the call flow more graphically